# Need help bootstrapping an AngularJS app into an Angular2 CLI generated app using ngUpgrade

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

I've been wrestling with this for almost a day now, so I think it's time I give up and ask for help.

I started with a trivial AngularJS application (1.4.7) that should simply display "Greetings from Angular 1", and have been trying to bootstrap that application into a trivial Angular2 CLI generated app.

It doesn't seem to work. Instead of "Greetings from Angular 1", I see "{{angular1Msg}}". The following commit shows exactly what I did to include and bootstrap the app. I've spent quite a bit of time now with the documentation and am not sure what I'm missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Project repo:
https://github.com/scottschafer/ng2hybrid

The commit in which I attempted to integrate the AngularJS app:
https://github.com/scottschafer/ng2hybrid/commit/4b2c7c5339388ec2b3debeae0643dff89b75926f

(note that the source for the AngularJS app lives in src/ng1app, and is a working standalone AngularJS 1.4.7 application).

Comment: I think you mixing angualrjs and angular 2 code. I would suggest you to go through code generated from angualr cli. go through `app.component.ts` and `app.component.html` to get started https://github.com/scottschafer/ng2hybrid/tree/master/src/app

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working. A lot of trial and error. Not much fun at all.

https://github.com/scottschafer/ng2hybrid